# Maximization of piecewise function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, piecewise

I'm trying to maximize piecewise functions with parameters but haven't been able to do so. Here is a minimum example:

```
f[x_, a_] = -(x - 10*a)^2 + 50*a;
w[x_, a_] = \[Piecewise] {
    {f[x, a], 1/2 < a < 8/x && 0 < x < 20},
    {-10, True}
   };
```

I want to maximize $w$ over $x$ ($a$ is a parameter). Any ideas on how to solve this symbolically (or even numerically with $a$ in a grid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Use the approach by @Bob Hanlon

```
f[x_, a_] = -(x - 10*a)^2 + 50*a;
w[x_, a_] = Piecewise[{{f[x, a], 1/2 < a < 8/x && 0 < x < 20}}, -10];
max1[a_] = Maximize[{w[x, a], a > 0}, x][[1]]
max2[a_] = Maximize[{w[x, a], a <= 0}, x][[1]]
Plot3D[w[x, a], {a, -2, 2}, {x, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
 MaxRecursion -> 4, ViewPoint -> Front, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
Plot[{max1[a], max2[a]}, {a, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

- When $a>0$,
  $$
  \begin{cases}
   -10 & a\geq \text{Root}\left[50 \text{$\#$1}^4-25 \text{$\#$1}^3-85 \text{$\#$1}^2+32\&,2\right]\lor 0<a\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
   50 a & a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\lor \frac{1}{2}<a<\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\
   -\frac{2 \left(50 a^4-25 a^3-80 a^2+32\right)}{a^2} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}<a<\text{Root}\left[50 \text{$\#$1}^4-25 \text{$\#$1}^3-85
     \text{$\#$1}^2+32\&,2\right] \\
   -\infty  & \text{True}
  \end{cases}
  $$
- When $a\leq 0$

$$
\begin{cases}
 -10 & a\leq 0 \\
 -\infty  & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

**Original**

Maybe this?

```
f[x_, a_] = -(x - 10*a)^2 + 50*a;
w[x_, a_] = Piecewise[{{f[x, a], 1/2 < a < 8/x && 0 < x < 20}}, -10];
max[a_] := NMaximize[w[x, a], x][[1]];
Plot3D[w[x, a], {a, -2, 2}, {x, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 ViewPoint -> Front, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
Plot[max[a], {a, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `max[a_] := MaxValue[{w[x, a], a > 0, x > 0}, x, Reals]` gives a smoother and more accurate plot. `({wmax, arg} = 
 Maximize[{w[x, a], x > 0, a > 0}, {a, x}, Reals]) // N // Quiet` evaluates to `{46.4011, {a -> 0.964128, x -> 8.29765}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, updated.

Comment: Beautiful approach! In going beyond the minimum example (more than two pieces functions), I wonder if there are any heuristics on how to partition the parameter set. Are there more or less general guidelines for choosing the number of intervals and for selecting the cutoff points?